# How can I see the changes I make when creating a ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, controltemplate

Maybe I am too ignorant to understand this, but I don't know how I can see changes that I am making when I create `ControlTemplate`, any `ControlTemplate`. For example, I'm creating `TextBox` `ControlTemplate`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="TextBoxTemplate" x:Key="TemplateForTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
        <Border Background="#215564">
            
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And I have a `Button` that dynamically creates a `TextBox`

```
void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = new Window();

            window.Show();
            window.Width = 250;
            window.Height = 250;
            window.Template = FindResource("WindowControlTemplate1") as ControlTemplate;
            
            dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
            Grid.SetRow(dynamicTextBox, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(dynamicTextBox, 0);
            this.TextPanel.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox);
            dynamicTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
            dynamicTextBox.Text = "";

            //Adjusting margin of text box
            Thickness margin = dynamicTextBox.Margin;
            margin.Top = 30;
            dynamicTextBox.Margin = margin;

            margin.Left = 10;
            dynamicTextBox.Margin = margin;

            margin.Bottom = -25;
            dynamicTextBox.Margin = margin;

            dynamicTextBox.Template = FindResource("TemplateForTextBox") as ControlTemplate;


        }
```

I can not see `TextBox` until I(user) press the `Button`, but I wanna see `TextBox`es design while I am writing XAML code(in other words until I press `Button`)

Comment: You mean how to apply it, like `<TextBox Template="{StaticResource TemplateForTextBox}"/>`?

Comment: The problem is that TextBox is created dynamically by button, and it has some design that is created by ControlTemplate. I wanna see this design without debugging

Comment: @thatguy
I edited the question, please check it one more time

Comment: The button click is executed at runtime, the designer cannot disply something that does not exist at design-time. It is much more favourable to design your control in XAML.

Comment: I mean how can I see what my control template will look like when applied to a TextBox? Not necessarily for dynamic TextBox(object).